# What is the time complexity of ternary search when applied on doubles?

Tags: algorithm

I know that the time complexity of the normal ternary search is O(log3 n), but what if it is used with floating point numbers?

An Example: What is the time complexity of this block of this block of code?

```
double s = -100, m1, m2, e = 100, EPS = 1e-6; 
while(abs(s-e) > EPS)
{     
    m1 = s + (e - s) / 3;
    m2 = e - (e - s) / 3;

    if(condition)
        e = m2;
    else
        s = m1;
}
```

All this does is search for a real number between -100 and 100, but the time complexity changes when the precision of the `EPS` variable changes.

Comment: Note: Log_3(n) = log(n)/log(3) -- In O(log n), the base is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

The complexity is `O(log 3(e-s)/EPS)`.  We can reduce the problem to the integer case where `n=ceil((e-s)/ESP)`.  (Here `ceil(x)` is the function that maps `x` to the next integer `j` such that `x <= j < x+1`.)

Let `delta = (e-s)/n <= EPS`. It's easy to verify that `delta <= EPS`.  At the `i`th step of the algorithm, either `s[i]` or `e[i]` has been moved from its predecessor (`s[i-1]` or `e[i-1]`) to a different interval `I[i]` given by `I[i] = (s+(i-1)*delta, s+i*delta] (i <= n)`, or else `s[i]` and `e[i]` are within `delta` of each other, in which case they are within `EPS` of each other.